# Can't insert to sqlite using c#, "id's are not unique" but in the sqlite app it works

Tags: c#, sqlite

My SQL query is

```
string stringSQL = "Insert into table(clientid, contractorid, driverid)
                    values (1,1,last_insert_rowid() + 1)"
ExecuteNonQuery(stringSQL)
```

And the error I get is:

> Error: abort due to constraint
>   violation(clientid, contractorid,
>   driverid are not unique.

Btw those columns are my primary keys!

Is there an issue using SQLite's functions in c# vs 2010?
Thx I advance

Comment: Do you mean to say that you have a composite primary key? So the combination of clientid, contractorid and driverid has to be unique? If so, you might want to add another meaningless id and make that the primary key. Composite key can be quite a hassle. Try refering to them or updating them...

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @Marc_s couldn't find the button on my iPad, sorry for it being ugly.

Comment: @Marc G.. I am not sure if I understand your question. I am using the function to get the last rowid and assign it to the driverid after i add 1.

Comment: @Yaron Buki: check out the [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) FAQ entry (including a screenshot)...

Comment: This was what I used to insert instead: <code> 'insert into table (aid, bid, cid) values (1,1, case when ( select count(*) from table where aid=1 and bid=1)=0 then 1 else (select max(cid) +1 from table) end)' </code> this check if there is a row if not 1 is assigned else add plus 1 to last row number. If somebody has a better way I am all ears. Thx

Answer (score 4):

From the [last_insert_rowid()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) documentation:

> The last_insert_rowid() function returns the ROWID of the last row insert from the database connection which invoked the function.

Note the "from the database connection" part... which means if there's already data in your table before you open this connection, presumably it's going to start from 0 or 1 again, and end up with a conflict. In other words, I don't think you can use this as a general way of incrementing row IDs.

I'd expect this to work if the table was empty before opening your current database connection, and if that connection is the only thing to have inserted data into that table though... you might want to test that part, just to make sure we understand what's going on.

That's assuming the docs are correct, of course - I've never actually used sqlite myself...

Comment: Jon, i am impresses. You hit the nail on the head. I tested your idea and "proved" your theory. Now i wonder how one would increment the driver id. I don't advice sqlite it is a lot harder to work with then other db's I used.

Comment: This was what I used to insert instead: